# rtabmap visual odometry

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, visual-odometry, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone,
i'm facing some error or strange behaviour when rotating my camera along the yaw axis. i'm running the handheld tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/HandHeldMapping) with a orbbec astra (running with the astra_camera ros package).
i put the camera on a tripod just to be sure to not translate my camera while rotating it, however the odometry shows an unexpected translation on the y axis (as you can see in the attached pictures).
Any sort of help will be very appreciated.

ps.
i'm not sure the browser to have attached my file.. in case you can find it here https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5G6Ct8c7jq7V3lMcWwzMThEMms

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253988/rtabmap-visual-odometry/) by [aerydna](https://answers.ros.org/users/27607/aerydna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2017-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the precision of the orbbec after 3-4 meters? If it is similar to Kinect, the odometry may think that the camera is translating instead of rotating. You can try the PnP transform estimation to be more robust to far noisy features:

```
$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros rgbd_mapping.launch rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start --Vis/EstimationType 1"
```

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2017-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0